# Ace editor (form) - Can I preserve line breaks/text format?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, ace-editor, sinatra-activerecord

Working on a project for my school building an MVC Sinatra application. I want to create a web app that can save and display back snippets/algos using ace editor.

I figured out how to (seemingly) capture form input through ace editor by hiding the input field and assigning the value from ace on change with the snippet below.

```
//CAPTURE/SET VALUE
var textarea = $('input[name="content"]');
editor.getSession().on("change", function () {
    textarea.val(editor.getSession().getValue());
});
```

my form looks like this

```
<!--ACE EDITOR-->
<div id="editor"></div>
To open settings panel, inside editor - CTRL+Q (Windows) | CMD+Q (Mac)
<!--------------------------------------------------------->

<!--FORM-->
<form action="/ace" method="POST"> 

  <!--normal-->
  <input type="text" name="content" style="display: none;" />

  <!--submit-->
  <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

I can capture the params fine but the problem is it doen't preserve the line breaks so entering...

```
def something

end
```

into ace editor and clicking submit gives me back

```
"def something  end"
```

when I would love in theory to get something like

```
"def something\n\nend"
```

or something of the sort.. you get the drift

I need to be able to somehow use the editor to capture input, and on submit assign that to an object attribute so pseudo

```
snippet = Snippet.new(:content => params[:content])
```

then be able to call that back and display back on editor in the right format

```
snippet.content (preserves linebreaks)
```

Full code and images [HERE](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1M1bbWzEA9hDKKGosaa6OPqLCnEaXcI_6z6y7qQisVHk/edit?usp=sharing) if you rather visuals.
Any help would be appreciated and if there is anything I'm missing out please let me know.. hope I've supplied sufficient info and detailed properly.

Comment: I think getting the value from the session provides with \n(new line break) also.. just do a split on \n and check whether you get something or not.

Comment: can you show me an example of what you mean ? if it's what i think you mean I tried that already and got back this https://i.imgur.com/tgIYXOg.png

Comment: i also tried `textarea.val(editor.getSession().getValue().split("\n").join("\n"));` in the js before setting the input value it works on browser console but when send to input still comes back without the breaks

Answer (score 1):

input doesn't accept newlines, you need to use textarea instead.

Comment: hey sorry for the late reply .. I tried using textarea but then I did the ace editor no longer displayed. I found a workaround, I'll add answer when I get the chance but here's my repo if you want to take a look at what I did and/or test what happens when change input to textarea repo: https://github.com/AlphaDaniel/snalgos